# On enter keypress, setting input field

Tags: jquery

I have the following code where I place a temporary input field and replace it with the hidden input field after the value is entered:

```
    var main =  function(evt){
        var textElement = $(this);
        var tempField = settings.tempInputField;

            textElement.hide();
            textElement.after(tempField);
            tempField.focus();

            tempField.on("blur, keypress", function (e){
                console.log(e.which);
            var hiddenField = settings.hiddenInputField,
                textValue = $(this).val(),
                textColor = settings.color;
                font = settings.textSize
                removeInputHandle = $(this).remove(),
                setText = textElement.show();

            if(textValue != ""){
                hiddenField.val(textValue).change();
                textElement.text(textValue);
                textElement.css("color", textColor);
                textElement.css("font-size", font);
                settings.callback();
            }

                if(e.which === 13){
                    removeInputHandle;
                    setText;
                }

            return textValue;
            });
        };
```

I can't get it to set the text when the enter key is pressed. Instead upon "blur", it sets the field. If I replace the .on function with a .on("keypress" , it sets the feild as soon as I press a key. I need it to set when I press key 13 (the enter key).

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this?

```
tempField.bind('blur keypress', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode==13){
        alert('bla');
    }
});
```

Comment: well, I got the enter key to work however now I can't get it to work upon blur